# How to run the ed editor from a Windows terminal?

Tags: windows, terminal, command-line, editor, ed

I followed all the correct steps and I'm still getting a "Invalid argument" error. Here the steps:

1. Manually install ed from here: https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ed.htm. Setup file is the ones that says "Complete package, except sources".
2. Adding the path (C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin) to the PATH system variable (tried with local variables too).
3. Tried running this command from Command Prompt and Powershell with elevated privileges:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\ed.exe" "{full-path-to-some-file.txt}"

I invariably get an "**Invalid argument**" error.

If I try to run just "ed", I get the same.

But if I type "ed --version" I get:

> GNU Ed 1.2
> Copyright (C) 1994 Andrew L. Moore, 2009 Antonio Diaz Diaz.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

And I type "ed --help" I get:

> GNU Ed - The GNU line editor.
>
> Usage: ed [options] [file]
> Options:
> -h, --help                 display this help and exit
> -V, --version              output version information and exit
> -G, --traditional          run in compatibility mode
> -l, --loose-exit-status    exit with 0 status even if a command fails
> -p, --prompt=STRING        use STRING as an interactive prompt
> -s, --quiet, --silent      suppress diagnostics
> -T, --textmode             input and output in textmode (EOL = CRLF)
> -v, --verbose              be verbose
> Start edit by reading in `file' if given. Read output of shell command if` file' begins with a `!'.
>
> Report bugs to bug-ed@gnu.org.
> Ed home page: http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/ed.html
> General help using GNU software: http://www.gnu.org/gethelp

So it seems to me that is correctly installed, but I still can't use it? I'm so confused.